# Programa que encripte y desencripte un texto (Principiante en programación)

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, script

estoy trabajando en un código que se encargue de encriptar y desencriptar texto recibido como parámetro. Ayer Alberto Siurob uno de los miembros de esta hermosa comunidad que guio un poco sobre el tema pero hay varios puntos que todavía no logro entender...

Los datos que me brindaron son los siguientes...

Las "llaves" de encriptación que utilizaremos son:

`La letra "e" es convertida para "enter"`
`La letra "i" es convertida para "imes"`
`La letra "a" es convertida para "ai"`
`La letra "o" es convertida para "ober"`
`La letra "u" es convertida para "ufat"`

La estructura que armé (con ayuda del amigo colaborador) fue la siguiente:

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
     <meta charset = "UTF-8">
     <title>  </title>
</head>

<body>

<input/>

<button> Encriptar </button>
<input/>
<button> Desencriptar </button>

 <script>
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var button.onclick
function cambiarVocal(input) {
      var letras = input.split('');

       var llaves = {
          a: 'ai',
          e: 'enter',
          i: 'imes',
          o: 'ober',
          u: 'ufat'
          };

      return cifrado = letras.map( letra => llaves[letra] ? llaves[letra] : letra).join('');}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

El código dentro de la etiqueta script funciona pero no entiendo símbolos como '=>', '?', dentro del .map. Quería saber si con un bucle for o while se podría hacer ya que la información que dispongo no es tan avanzada. Osea encriptar las vocales con un loop y desencriptarlas. Tampoco sé como darle funcionalidad a los botones de encriptar y desencriptar. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: La info acerca de los operadores `=>` y `?` puedes encontrarla en la documentación de JS. Recuerda que [es.so] es un sitio para preguntas _específicas_: estás incluyendo múltiples preguntas en una sola, y parte de ella se responde _buscando en la documentación_. Por último, no olvides que este sitio _no es un foro de discusión_.

Comment: Sobre el interrogante u [operador condicional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Sobre las [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Gracias  Pablo Lozano. Y si perdón hice muchas preguntas en una sola. En las próximas preguntas tendré más cuidado. Gracias.